# NSubstitute returning empty string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nunit, nsubstitute

I have the following method under test:

```
public HomeController(IUserIpAddressHelper userIpAddressHelper)
{
    _userIpAddressHelper = userIpAddressHelper;
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var userIpAddress = _userIpAddressHelper.GetUserIpAddress(System.Web.HttpContext.Current);
    if (_userIpAddressHelper.IsIpAddressOddOrEven(userIpAddress))
    {
        return RedirectToAction(HomePage);
    }
    
    return RedirectToAction(HomePageAlternative);
}
```

and I am testing as follows:

```
public void Test()
{
    var userIpAddressHelper = Substitute.For<IUserIpAddressHelper>();
    userIpAddressHelper.GetUserIpAddress(Arg.Any<HttpContext>()).Returns("0.0.0.2");
  
    var controller = new HomeController(userIpAddressHelper);

    var result = controller.Index();

    Assert.IsInstanceOf<RedirectToRouteResult>(result);

    var redirectToRouteResult = result as RedirectToRouteResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(HomeController.HomePage, redirectToRouteResult.RouteValues["action"]);
}
```

However the test is failing due to the value of `userIpAddress` being `""` an empty string, instead of  `0.0.0.2` as I've set it. Can anyone please point out where I've gone wrong here?

Comment: I doubt `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is set to anything meaningful in your unit-test. You should mock that context and pass the mocked object to your method. E.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4379450/mock-httpcontext-current-in-test-init-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `userIpAddress` definitely `""`? It looks like the `Returns` in your original test is specified well, but if `IUserIpAddressHelper` is an interface then the substitute for it will not have a result stubbed for `IsIpAddressOddOrEven`, so it will always return `false` even if `GetUserIpAddress` is stubbed to return `"0.0.0.2"`.

To get the test to mirror how the production code passes through the data, you can stub out both members:

```
var userIpAddressHelper = Substitute.For<IUserIpAddressHelper>();
userIpAddressHelper.GetUserIpAddress(Arg.Any<HttpContext>()).Returns("0.0.0.2");
userIpAddressHelper.IsIpAddressOddOrEven("0.0.0.2").Returns(true);
```

This will test that the production code correctly passes through the result of `GetUserIpAddress` to `IsIpAddressOddOrEven`.

Note: we could also stub these to work with `"ip-address-result"` and it would still work. We don't need a valid odd/even result returned, as we are not using a real implementation of `IUserIpAddressHelper`, just a substitute for testing. If you find it necessary to substitute for `IUserIpAddressHelper` in lots of tests and you want it to act like a real implementation (i.e. it will actually return whether an address is odd or even), it might be easier to write a `TestUserIpAddressHelper`.

Another way to avoid having the dependency between the results of `GetUserIpAddress` and `IsIpAddressOddOrEven` is to change the interface to have a `bool IsIpAddressOddOrEven(HttpContext context)` method that combines both operations. That way you would only need to stub one for the test.

Answer (score 0):

If you have problems with `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`, you can try to mock `IsIpAddressOddOrEven` method instead. They will both do the same job for your test.
Like this:

```
public void Test()
{
    var userIpAddressHelper = Substitute.For<IUserIpAddressHelper>();
    userIpAddressHelper.IsIpAddressOddOrEven(Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(true);
  
    var controller = new HomeController(userIpAddressHelper);

    var result = controller.Index();

    Assert.IsInstanceOf<RedirectToRouteResult>(result);

    var redirectToRouteResult = result as RedirectToRouteResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(HomeController.HomePage, redirectToRouteResult.RouteValues["action"]);
}
```